# PowerBI filter table based on value of measure_A OR measure_B

Tags: filter, powerbi

I need to show in table in PowerBI filtered results based on value of one measure > 30 OR value of other measure > 50 and have no clue how can I do it.

To explain it simple:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE "Parameter1">30 OR "Parameter2">50
```

But how to implement something like this in PowerBI.

Comment: You'll find two ways to do exactly that here: [Power BI Dashboard where the core filter condition is a disjunction on numeric fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142005/power-bi-dashboard-where-the-core-filter-condition-is-a-disjunction-on-numeric-f/52274103#52274103)

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem, sorry, I didn't find it. But still - there is no solution, so the problem still exitst.

Comment: No solution? Did you try any of the suggestions?

Comment: You're right, the trick with filter measure works. Thank You.

Comment: No problem at all!