# "not" & "and" filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables `Unit`, `UnitOption` and `Option`. `Unit` is related to `UnitOption` with `UnitKey`, `UnitOpion` is related to `Option` with the `OptionKey`.

```
UnitOption 123 has options 35B, 12A, 51G, 
unitOption 456 has options 66F, 12A, 77X, 
UnitOption 789 has options 35B, 21G, 12a, 
unitOption 925 has options 89K, 5FR, 53F
```

In my results set I want to see units that do not have `Option 12A` AND DO NOT have `Option 35B`. In this example, my result set would be Units `456` and `925`. Neither of these units has both option `12A` and `35B`.

How do I do a "NOT" and "AND" slicer?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, `not (A and B)` is equivalent to `(not A) or (not B)`, so you can think of it that way if you prefer.

In any case, you'll want to create a new unrelated table of options to use as your slicer and then write a filter with the logical condition that you want, as explained in my answer to this similar question:

[Power BI Dashboard where the core filter condition is a disjunction on numeric fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142005)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL use `IN` for arrays

```
select * from Unit,UnitOption Where Unit.Key = UnitOption.UnitKey AND UnitOption.OptionKey NOT IN ('12A','35B');
```