# Union table to itself with propagated filter

Tags: powerbi, union, dax, selectedvalue

I'm new to Power BI and DAX, so bear with me.

I needed to union a table to itself when it is filtered. I need the filter from `DimCompanySupplier[VAT]` to propagate to `InterestCategory[VAT]` and union the result set from both filtered tables, all from the first input filter.

I am struggling to find the solution, I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

```
OpportunitiesByVAT =
VAR SelectedVat = SELECTEDVALUE ( DimCompanySupplier[VAT]; "ALL" )
RETURN
    UNION (
        CALCULATETABLE ( FactActiveOpportunities; DimCompanySupplier[VAT] = SelectedVat );
        CALCULATETABLE ( FactActiveOpportunities; InterestCategory[VAT] = SelectedVat )
    )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your DAX attempt looks pretty decent. How is it not working like you want?

Comment: Hi Alexis! Thank you for formatting my entry. The error I'm getting is that the expression refers to multiple columns, and these cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Comment: Where are you inputting this formula? It won't work as a calculated column or measure since it returns a table since those can only take on a single value at a time.

Comment: I was trying to pass it as a measure, but I can pass it as a calculated table. The problem is that I can't get the filters to work afterwards. I'm connecting the dimensions to the new fact, and the filtering is not working.

Comment: A calculated table cannot be responsive to filters (it's only calculated once whenever the model is loaded or refreshed), but you can use tables inside of a measure as long as the final output is a scalar.

Comment: I see. I just wanted to slice my table with one value for two dimensions, with union on the two different subsets, so that whenever I slice by DimCompanySupplier[VAT], it also shows the values for InterestCategory[VAT] where both Vats are equal. If slice by DimCompanySupplier[VAT], I will exclude records that I would like to show as well when I slice with InterestCategory[VAT]. My problem is more on the report level, rather than loading or modelling level (I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing your underlying problem to this question, your difficulty appears to be that you want a slicer that works using OR logic rather than AND logic.

Fortunately, this has been answered before. Please refer to this post:

[Power BI Dashboard where the core filter condition is a disjunction on numeric fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142005/power-bi-dashboard-where-the-core-filter-condition-is-a-disjunction-on-numeric-f)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Though I'm still struggling to implement it, and the Union solution is just one of the ways I was addressing the problem. I'll look into it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Alex. The solution you've given me works fine, but I would like to ask, what if one of the tables I want to filter with has a many to many relationship with the table I want to filter?